# How to delete a specific sublement by key in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

How does one remove an array element by key?

The docs seem to indicate it's as simple as identifying the key by name, but this doesn't seem to work.

For example, with the images array below, and a key of `59db1c3654819952005897`, I'm unable to remove the element (the code below produces no errors, but doesn't remove anything):

```
updateOne(['_id' => 34], ['$pull' => ["images" => "59db1c3654819952005897"]])
```

Here is the data structure:

```
"_id" : 34,  
"images": [
    {
        "59db1c3654819952005897": {
            "name": "1024x1024.png",
            "size": "19421",
            "sort": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "59db1c3652cda581935479": {
            "name": "200x200.png",
            "size": "52100",
            "sort": 3
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is because your `pull` query is looking for a document where the value of `images` is equal to `59db1c3654819952005897` and in your case, it's not true.

Even if you try to perform a `find` query with the params you've specified, it will return no result:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({
    'images': '59db1c3654819952005897'
});
```

To solve it, you must find a query that will be able to retrieve your document, which would be the following:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({
    'images': {
        '59db1c3654819952005897': {
            '$exists': true
        }
    }
});
```

Now to update your `$pull` query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').updateOne({'_id': 34}, {
    '$pull': {
        'images': {
            '59db1c3654819952005897': {
                '$exists': true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So in PHP it would be:

```
$id = '59db1c3654819952005897';
updateOne(['_id' => 34], ['$pull' => [
    'images' => [
        $id => [
            '$exists' => true
        ]
    ]
]]);
```

In other words, it's going to pull in the `images` array if `59db1c3654819952005897` exists inside for the document with an `_id` of value `34`.

Comment: I guess that makes sense... although it's odd that given a key you would also have to add "if it exists"
Thanks!

Comment: Because you're comparing the `key` as a `value` instead! You welcome :)